# Automating cell movement preferably using if/when style conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

[image]

I want to fully automate the process of cleaning up exported data. I want to:

- Move the data in the overflow rows into their prospective column. I have tried the following code in VB. (This is trying to identify the @ symbol in the emails and respectively move all email address two places to the right).

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim D As Range, r As Range
    Set D = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("D:D"))
```

`For Each r In D
    If Left(r.Text, 2) = "@" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r End Sub`

- Once the data is in the correct column I need to automate the movement into the correct row. I can easily have them shift up but if one contact doesn't have an email address (as an example) then the emails will be in the wrong rows when they shift up.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim y As Integer, x As Integer

    y = 2
    Do Until Cells(y, 4) = ""
        If Cells(y, 3) = "" Then
            Select Case Left(Cells(y, 4))
                Case "[E": x = 6
                Case "[H": x = 7
                Case "[M": x = 8
                Case "[A": x = 9
                Else: x = 10
            End Select
            Cells(y - 1, x) = Cells(y, 4)
            Rows(y).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Some remarks on your original VBA:

- "This is trying to identify the @ symbol in the emails ...": `left(r.Text,2)` selects the first two character of a string, it will never be equal to a one character long string ("@")! (my code decides location based on first character after [)
- "and respectively move all email address two places to the right" - your code is `OFFSET(0,1)`, which is just one column to the right, always check consistency of your code.
- "Once the data is in the correct column I need to automate the movement into the correct row" - my code does both in the same step, beside shorter code, it's even more simpler.